# how to find the biggest value and limit 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to find the biggest value. And the value store like : "C100,C201,C423, M1100,M200, N3000, N3333"

Please help me to solve this problem. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Some more explanation is needed here. How are you quantifying the 'biggest' value? If that's the output, what's the input?

Comment: @Kim Hong As far as I remember, this question was asked before. Did you try searching for an answer before asking?

Comment: i don't know how to search it.

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? Why is the output as it is (the ruleset)? If the posted string is the input(?), what would be the "biggest value" and why?

Comment: My purpose is i have is i have a  select dropdown there are " Construction, Marine, Manufacture, Oil and Gas, And Transportation and Logistics"  When I choose Construction it also insert 1 data by input hidden with "C [number]", if i select Marine it will start with "M[number]".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Look this images all values in my DB

[image]

Now i put my query and get result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what i want is max of C. or max of M.